# How to redisplay parse login from child view controller in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, parse-platform, uitabbarcontroller

I have a view controller which is triggered from a UITabBarController (which is the root of my app) if a parse session doesn't exist.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    self.initialiseLogin()
}

func initialiseLogin()
{
    if (PFUser.currentUser() == nil) {
        let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc: UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginView") as! UIViewController
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Which works great. However the problem i'm having is how do i trigger this code when a logout is called from a child view controller in the tab bar controller

```
@IBAction func logoutAction(sender: AnyObject)
{
    PFUser.logOut()
    // ... what should i call here...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Protocols and delegates might be what you're looking for:
[The Swift Programming Language - Protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html)

Essentially, you can declare your `UIViewController`s to conform to a protocol. Then set the delegates in your root view controller (or wherever you do your initialisation)

Then, you can do something like this:

```
@IBAction func logoutAction(sender: AnyObject)
{
    PFUser.logOut()
    delegate?.loggedOut()
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Just needed to get my head back into event driven patterns.